# Add Null rows to table in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, null, mdx, inner-join

I have this table:

```
ROW_GROUP           COL_GROUP         CLAIM_COUNT      DENIAL_AMOUNT
NOT MEDIC NEC/PRE-X October 2010    6                591.50
NOT MEDIC NEC/PRE-X November 2010   8                3154.48
DUPLICATE             October 2010    39               7921.78
DUPLICATE             November 2010   35               7484.17
REGISTRATION           October 2010    56               10622.55
REGISTRATION           November 2010   67               7820.69
TIMELY FILING          September 2010  6                239.00
TIMELY FILING          October 2010 67               8389.25
TIMELY FILING         November 2010   6                51127.96
```

I need to be able to add September (or any COL_GROUP field) to this table with nulls in claim_count and denial_amount. ROW_GROUP and COL_GROUP are dynamically generated so I can't just update the fields, this has to be done within a stored procedure. It was mentioned that a outer left join might create these nulls for me, just not sure how. Any suggestions would be helpful.

It was suggested to use this sql statement from a colleague at work, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
select #TREND.ROW_GROUP, DISTINCTTIME.COL_GROUP, #TREND.CLAIM_COUNT, #TREND.DENIAL_AMOUNT from (select distinct #TREND.COL_GROUP from #TREND) 
AS DISTINCTTIME LEFT OUTER JOIN #TREND ON 
DISTINCTTIME.COL_GROUP = #TREND.COL_GROUP
```

Comment: Can you show us the query you're using to insert rows?

Comment: if you want help with altering some existing SQL you need to provide the SQL

Comment: Its a stored procedure that returns this information. It actually uses a cube (SSAS) to get the information. The cube result gets stored in a temp table then I just use a generic Select * from #TREND

Answer (score 0):

The reason I needed to do this was Report Builder wasn't viewing the dates as actually dates and couldn't trend them. I solved this using a sql function. I'm posting this here for anyone dealing with MDX and having to deal with weird dates.

```
USE [DMDS]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[MonthFormat]    Script Date: 12/02/2010 14:02:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[MonthFormat](@date varchar(25)) Returns date as 
    Begin 
        declare @retval as varchar(50) 
        select @retval = case 
            when @date like 'Jan%' then '01/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Feb%' then '02/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'March%' then '03/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Apr%' then '04/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'May%' then '05/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Jun%' then '06/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Jul%' then '07/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Aug%' then '08/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Sept%' then '09/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Oct%' then '10/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Nov%' then '11/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            when @date like 'Dec%' then '12/01/' + RIGHT(@Date,4)
            End
    return @retval
End
```